# Azure DevOps 2019 On-Premises instance Dashboards

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We currently have an Azure DevOps 2019 on-premises instance and have provisioned a new organisation on `dev.azure.com`. We are looking at integrating our on-premises Dashboards with `dev.azure.com` so that we can get a holistic view across both instances. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try migrating your collection data from on-premises server to azure devops cloud service. Then you can reconfigure your dashboards to include data migrated from the on-premises server.

There are migration tools you can use. Check out **[Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/)**

You can also check the the data migration tool provided by Microsoft. But it seems [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/555369/migrate-tfs-to-azure-devops-services-into-existing.html) that it only allow to migrate the on-premises collections to an empty new organization on azure devops services. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops) for more information.